# repo init command for Downloading Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, repository

I wanted to download a particular version of Android  - Android 4.1.2
What will be the steps for that :

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest **-b android-4.1.2** ??

PLz suggest !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem is which tag use (i.e. the value of the `-b` option): you have to look at the tags defined in the manifest file repository that you can find [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+refs).

Furthemore there is this page from the official documentation: http://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html